# Randomize datatable by column without losing attributes or changing type

Tags: r, attributes, sample

My goal is to randomize the value sequence within a datatable *by column* without losing the attributes associated with each column. Each column should be randomized independently of each other column. So a dataset that looked like this:

| ID | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 54 | 120 |
| B | 48 | 200 |
| C | 32 | 250 |

might end up looking like this:

| ID | height | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C | 48 | 250 |
| A | 54 | 200 |
| B | 32 | 120 |

Replicable example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(labelled)

dat<-data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                b=c("one","two","three","four","five"),
                c=c(10,9,8,7,6))

var_label(dat$a)<-"The a variable"
var_label(dat$b)<-"The b variable"
var_label(dat$c)<-"The c variable"

val_label(dat$a,1)<-"First option"
val_label(dat$a,2)<-"Second option"
val_label(dat$a,3)<-"Third option"
val_label(dat$a,4)<-"Fourth option"
val_label(dat$a,5)<-"Fifth option"

new_dat<-as.data.table(apply(dat,2,sample))
```

The problem is this:

```
str(dat$a)
 dbl+lbl [1:5] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
 @ labels: Named num [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "First option" "Second option" "Third option" "Fourth option" ...
 @ label : chr "The a variable"

str(new_dat$a)
 chr [1:5] "2" "3" "5" "4" "1"
```

I have a medium-sized dataset (~10,000 rows and ~250 columns), and I'm going to need to replicate this, so I don't really want a random solution. Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve interrogating the structure of each column of dat and coercing each matching column of new_dat to match? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `apply` (which converts to `matrix` and matrix can have only a single class).  Use `lapply`

```
newdat <- copy(dat)
newdat[] <- lapply(newdat, sample)
```

-check the structure

```
str(newdat)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ a: dbl+lbl [1:5] 2, 3, 4, 5, 1
#   ..@ labels: Named num  1 2 3 4 5
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "First option" "Second option" "Third option" "Fourth option" ...
#   ..@ label : chr "The a variable"
# $ b: chr  "five" "three" "two" "one" ...
# $ c: num  6 10 8 7 9
```

---

Or another fast option is `dapply` from `collapse` (which does preserve the type and attributes)

```
library(collapse)
newdat <- dapply(newdat, sample)
```

---

Infact never use `apply` if the dataset have more one type (in different columns).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you first for a working answer, then for another even better answer.